# Did Harry meet Charlie Weasley before Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

In chapter five of *Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire*, Harry meets two of the Weasley brothers whom he never met before, Charlie and Bill.

> Harry looked around and saw that Ron and George were sitting at the scrubbed wooden table with two red-haired people Harry had never seen before, though he knew immediately who they must be: Bill and Charlie, the two eldest Weasley brothers.

But hadn't Harry already met Charlie before while giving away the dragon baby which Hagrid won in cards. Is this a continuity error?

Comment: A "bug in the story", as you call it, is usually called a plot hole.

Comment: I'm not even sure this is a "plot hole," since the story doesn't depend at all on Charlie being new to Harry. It would be a continuity error, if it was anything.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Charlie didn't come to pick up Norbert

In his response letter to Ron, Charlie says that Norbert will be picked up by some "friends" who are coming to visit him:

> I'd be glad to take the Norwegian Ridgeback, but it won't be easy getting him here. I think the best thing will be to send him over with some friends of mine who are coming to visit me next week.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 14: "Norbert the Norwegian Ridgeback"</sup>

And when the tradeoff actually takes place, only Charlie's friends are present:

> Chuckling about Malfoy, they waited, Norbert thrashing about in his crate. About ten minutes later, four broomsticks came swooping down out of the darkness.
>
> Charlie's friends were a cheery lot.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 14: "Norbert the Norwegian Ridgeback"</sup>

So no, Harry and Charlie had never met in person.

Answer (score 26):

## Charlie didn't take the dragon, his friends did.

Harry had only sent a letter to Charlie in Romania.

From the letter that Ron sent to Charlie:

> I think the best thing will be to send him over with some friends of mine who are coming to visit me next week.
>   ...
>   They can meet you there and take him away while it’s still dark.

And an actual scene:

> Charlie’s friends were a cheery lot.

Answer (score 16):

While the other answers are correct that Harry had never met Charlie Weasley before, there's still an argument that a continuity error exists.

The text reads:

> Harry looked around and saw that Ron and George were sitting at the scrubbed wooden table with two red-haired people **Harry had never seen before**, though he knew immediately who they must be: Bill and Charlie, the two eldest Weasley brothers.

While he had never met either of them before, he had **seen** them in the picture from the Daily Prophet from the Weasley's trip to Egypt in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*.

> Harry scanned the moving photograph, and a grin spread across his face as he saw all nine of the Weasleys waving furiously at him, standing in front of a large pyramid. Plump little Mrs. Weasley; tall, balding Mr. Weasley; six sons; and one daughter, all (though the black-and-white picture didn’t show it) with flaming-red hair.

Comment: Did JKR step here out of her usual third person limited into omniscient? How the narrator knows about the red hair of those Weasleys Harry haven't met?

Comment: @Lt.Ortega Harry had seen the other members of the Weasley family and while technically he can't see the actual colours in the picture, he _does_ know what the hair colour of the people he _did_ see is - and while reading the colour from a black&white picture can be a bit difficult, it's usually *not* that difficult to tell that two things have (probably) the same colour. Add to that the fact that family resemblance adds a huge prior probability of any unknown Weasley having red hair, and you get a chance at making a very good guess.

Comment: @witchy From the first book: *"Think my name's funny, do you? No need to ask who you are. My father told me **all the Weasleys have red hair**, freckles, and more children than they can afford."*

Comment: @Alex oops, missed that